# Eager to meet or eager to meeting?

Tags: sentence-construction, infinitive-vs-gerund

Which is correct? "I am always eager to meeting you..." or "I am always eager to meet you......"

I for some reason think that 'meeting' should be used because it's being  referred in future.

Answer (score 3):

"Meeting" is the present continuous form of the base verb "meet".

When you use a verb in the *infinitive* form, ie "*to* meet", the general rule is to use the base form of the word, so you should not say "*to* meeting".

The correct sentence from your examples is:

> I am always eager *to meet* you.

The source of your confusion may be that you see the word combination "*to meeting*" used in examples like this:

> I look forward to meeting you.

Here, "to" is being used as a *preposition*. You are "looking forward to" the moment of meeting someone just as you might say, for example:

> I look forward to tomorrow.

Obviously, "tomorrow" is not a verb. What you have here is a preposition (to) and a gerund (meeting). Infinitives never have an *-ing* ending.